# Is inline Javascript more prefered than inside <script></script> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Which one is more supportive or preferable to use, and why?

**for an example:**

Inline javascript inside html tags like this:

Html:
`<input type="button" value="click" onclick="doFunction()" />`

and calling that function like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function doFunction()
    {
      alert("Hello World");
    }
</script>
```

or just do like this (with jquery):

html:
`<input type="button" value="click" />`

Jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $("input[type='button']").click(function(){
          alert("Hello World");
      });
   });
</script>
```

---

Kindly provide some links of articles that is related to the answer.

Thank you.

Comment: Separate logic from markup is the best approach. You don't need jQuery though. You can use `addEventListener` in plain JS, or just `el.onclick = function(){}`

Comment: Inline event handlers are in no way prefered, and you should stick with external event handlers if you can.

Comment: Inline javascript and jQuery are not mutually exclusive. If you really wanted, you could have jQuery expressions in inline code. So the issue is not "inline javascript vs. jquery"; it is whether or not to have inline code - and the answer is "not".

Comment: This is a call for opinions, discussion, and debate, not a technical question suitable for SO. Besides, it excludes the third option of using external scripts, which is often mentioned as the most preferable way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Best practice is to have your concerns separate. The html should show the display, and the javascript should make it dynamic. That being said, I would suggest having your html with an easy way to be targeted if it is to be used

```
<input id="btnClick" type="button" value="click" />
```

and then targeting that specific element for use

```
$("#btnClick").click(function(){ alert("click"); });
```

Overall though, if you are making a small site, only include jQuery if you are going to use a lot of the functionality. If you only need to use jQuery for the `click` event handler, then it would be best to do this with plan javascript (note that anything done in jquery can be done in javascript)

```
document.getElementById("btnClick").onclick = function(){ alert("click"); };
```

Comment: So, Jquery is most preferable instead of inline Javascript?

Comment: Hes saying inline is never preferred and that jQuery is framework of Javascript that makes it simple to write and understand by providing you with predesigned functions.

Comment: @Shovon - If you have already included the library, then yes. Otherwise, it is preferable to use javascript, but never inline.

Comment: @TravisJ- It would be helpful for me, if you provide some articles' links. Where I can read why inline javascript is not preferable at all. Thank you.

Comment: @Shovon The reason lies with the concept of [Separation of Concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns). The second item in the Examples section of that page is specifically HTML/CSS/JS. HTML is the content itself, CSS is the styling and presentation of the content, and JS is the functionality and user interaction of the content. Separation of Concerns says that since each of those technologies concerns itself with a different aspect of a webpage, they should remain separate. By inlining JS into HTML, you would be inserting functionality into your content space.

Comment: @Shovon - Sure, just [google unobstrusive javascript](https://www.google.com/search?q=unobtrusive%20javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Some reasons why it is preferable to avoid inline event listeners:

1. Keeping script logic separate from theme / gui layer (as others have stated).
2. It is difficult to stack or namespace inline event listeners. i.e. have more than one event listener applied to the same event.
3. Inline event listeners have to rely on variables in the global namespace, so making use of an externally wrapped local scope for your event listeners is impossible, without first exposing those variables globally. *e.g. you have a loop that finds/generates multiple link tags and you wish to apply a click listener that references a variable you have in wrapped local scope. This is not possible using inline events.*
4. Inline event listeners used to be more prone to memory leaks in older browsers, due to circular references between the inline code and the node object itself. I do not know if this is still true of modern user agents.
5. You have no control over when the event is trapped, using addEventListener you have a choice between the capture or bubble phase in most browsers.
6. As inline event listeners in markup are text-based (i.e. not function based), there is no way of appling the same code to many elements. Instead you have to duplicate the text, which is then converted into a new event listener for each element — wasting resources.
7. inline event listeners may have strange behaviours when their element is removed and re-appended in the Dom. It is not something I have ever tried but I would assume the event listener attribute would be re-evaluated on re-insertion to the dom, which would be unoptimal, and may even have unexpected results.
8. With inline event listeners in markup you have no way of feature testing that the event is supported before implementing the listener. Whilst using properly separated javascript you can check that `if ( typeof elm.ondblclick != 'undefined' ) { ... }` is true before applying your listener, or deciding to degraded to a fallback. You can obviously implement all your possible listeners as part of the markup, but this may have undesired effects.

Comment: Point 3: Wrapped local scope is *not* impossible in inline code. If you really wanted, you *could* write `onclick="$(function(){...})"`, with all the scoping advantages of doing the same thing inside `<script></script>` tags. The big difference would be that the click event would need to occur before the code became active. I am definitely not recommending this, just saying it's possible.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot Sorry I should have been clearer. What you state is possible, but using wrapped scope -- in a way that would more likely -- i.e. having your code generate or find elements and then attach listeners to them (which then have access to wrapped scope) is not possible, for you would have to expose something globally first for the inline events to pick up. I'll rewrite my statement.